# Leave a chat room, but not really

Tags: bug, chat

Click "leave" in a chat room; you'll still be listed as in it on the list of users that appears for that room in the list of rooms that appears after you click "leave". This is true even if you reload that page after a minute.

**NOTE:** This is not reproducible at the moment: it occurs sometimes, but not other times, and I can't figure out which times are which. *I'm posting this in an effort to solicit answers (or edits), based on others' experiences, that try to pin this bug down.*

Comment: If you are only waiting a couple seconds it is most likely cached data.

Comment: @JoshMein, I just tried it now: waited 60 seconds, reloaded the page, and I was still listed there.

Comment: The data can still be cached after 60 seconds. It all depends on how often the developers are getting the list of users in each room. In my opinion that kind of data isnt very important so I wouldnt be surprised if they cache it for a while.

Comment: Caching. If something seems wrong, it's probably caching.