# It seems like a loophole that I'll have to go into a room to leave the other room

Tags: support, chat

If I click "leave" in a chat room, as many of you know, I could still be there. I've read two posts on it (one posted seven years ago, the other two years ago), and it seems to be a bug that has yet to be fixed.

Currently, to leave all rooms, I go to another chat room, and if I see some chat rooms that the box says I'm in,  
I click "leave" there, but what about the room I'm currently in?

I want to know if there is a way I can leave all the chat rooms *without* entering one.

---

To clarify, I want to know **if there could be something like a *Leave* button beside each room** that the *mine* tab displays.

It's so annoying how **the *Leave* button inside the room doesn't always work**.

I would

1. click on the button, getting redirected to rooms list
2. refresh the page a few times to see if my avatar is still in the room
3. if my avatar is still in the room, open the room link again to select the *Leave* button. *(I once had to do this and repeat for up to 3 times before I can finally leave the room)*

**At first I didn't refresh the page**, I simply checked to see if my avatar was still in the room, but this led me to think I was still in the room when I actually already left. Must be some Google cache reason, **but it led me to enter the room again** *(pretty embarrassing)*, and only then did I found out it wasn't necessary.

Comment: Can't you click *all* next to *leave*?

Comment: Wouldn't work. Still in rooms.

Comment: Visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/leave/all  and click leave there. How do you determine that you're still in a chat room? Did you look [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/13552470/ann-zen?tab=general&rooms=current)? Keep in mind that the room list is cached so it takes some time before your avatar gets removed from the chat tile.

Comment: I worked, but I couldn't reproduce the link you gave me.

Comment: On which chat server are you trying this? What do you see if you visit that link and what happens if you click the leave button

Comment: stack overflow.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot as to where to click to go to the link you gave me?

Comment: @AnnZen you might be using more than one device, e.g. if you have a chat room open both in a browser on desktop computer and on a mobile device, you'll indeed have to leave on each device otherwise you'll still be in the room. There's no "Force leave on all devices" link.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Thank,  but I believe the problem is solved. I just need to know where this link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/leave/all came from. (I am only using one device.)

Comment: @AnnZen the link is inside any chat room, see the screenshot in the answer. If you don't see the same thing there might be a bug, please provide a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: The question as asked is a support question, not a feature request - and that's what the answer responds to. If you want to request a new feature or report a bug (that the button doesn't always work) you're welcome to do that but changing this question invalidates the existing answer.

Comment: @Catija Sorry, but I feel I haven't explained myself good enough.

Comment: @AnnZen you just can't change a support question into a feature request when there are answers present already. Start a new question in that case.

Comment: @Luuklag Okay, sorry. I was trying to improve my posts so I can earn my privilege to ask questions again...

Comment: Turning an already downvoted question into a feature request isn't going to help with that. It probably will only attract more downvotes.

Comment: Some older posts which describe that leave is not always reliable: [Leave a chat room, but not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175168), [Persistent chat room login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181530), [Trapped – you can join a chat room, but you can never leave](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225658).

Comment: @Martin Thanks! I read about it, and is stated in my post: *"one posted 7 years ago"*

Comment: Just close the browser or tabs where you have the chat open. This will trigger auto-leave after few minutes. That's what I do, and I very rarely use the "leave" button as I don't really care that I appear as I'm in the room for the few minutes until auto leave triggers.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Thanks! Are you sure it happens every time?

Comment: @AnnZen yes, 100% sure - there is mechanism in chat that check for a "keep alive" AJAX calls from the client to the server. Once the server doesn't get such call from the client for a period of time (not sure about exact time, but sure it does exist) it assumes the user is no longer active and initiates the "leave" process. Note it works only when you close all rooms in a domain. Keeping one open means you're still around, so even if you closed tab of other rooms, you won't "leave" them. (i.e. the signal is per-domain, not room.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a leave all rooms link -

[image: Screenshot of the room infobox in the Tavern on the Meta there's a red circle around the word "(all)" next to "leave" in the lower left corner.]

This should kick you out of all rooms on that server - remember that there are three chat servers, Chat.Meta, Chat.SO, and Chat.SE.

Clicking gives the following popup:

[image: Screenshot of a popup that reads "chat.stackoverflow.com says: This will remove you from all rooms; continue?" with buttons for "cancel" and "OK" as options]

After clicking "OK", all rooms on that server return to `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/`. Viewing the "mine" tab - rooms that you're currently in - it's empty.

[image: Screenshot of a view of the mentioned page. It says "a list of rooms you're currently in, most recent first" there are no rooms listed]

If this isn't what you're experiencing, please be more detailed about what you are experiencing. I have only tested it on Chat.SO because I'm in too many rooms on the other servers to rejoin them all easily.

Comment: The OP stated that this doesn't work

Comment: I just used it and it worked fine... All of the chat room pages reloaded to return to `chat.stackoverflow.com`. If it's not working, please describe what you're experiencing in more detail.

Comment: Uh...how do we know that the "all" link, in contrast to the "leave" link, *actually* works?

Comment: @ChristianRau ... the "mine" page is empty... as I show in the answer.

Comment: @Catija Note that you posting under this answer didn't bring any notification to my inbox.

Comment: @AnnZen It wasn't directed at you and you're not (I'm guessing) following the answer... so, no... it wouldn't notify you.

Comment: so... who's it directed to? :/

Comment: @AnnZen To be clear... when I say "directed at" I mean no one was at mentioned... it was intended for you but you deleted your comment, presumably because it duplicated Daniil's own comment... but I was assuming you were following the discussion and didn't need a ping. I was also in the middle of updating the answer... and, also, since you deleted your comment, even if I had pinged you, you wouldn't have been pinged, since your comment was deleted.

Comment: Alternatively you could visit the [currenly in rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=general&rooms=current) tab on your chat profile.

Comment: Okay, the point of the OP is that you have indeed to join a chatroom to be able to click on that (all)  link. The route to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/leave/all is not linked anywhere else except from that location you put the, not free hand :( ,  red circle on. So the question of the OP is: How do I leave all chatrooms without first joining a room. The answer is: You can't, you need to use a loop hole.

Comment: @rene Blame Preview. It was freehand and the stupid app auto-converts and I missed canceling it until after I'd uploaded. The question doesn't actually specify that - "*I want to know if there is a way I can leave all the chat rooms.*"

Comment: @rene Well you only need that link if you have joined a room. If you haven't joined a room there aren't any rooms you can leave from.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct link to the Leave All function.

You can visit the URL `/chats/leave/all` by typing it in the address bar of your browser to show the leave all page and then click the *Leave* button.

[image: Leave: Are you sure you want to leave all rooms? button labelled leave]

For your convenience here are the direct links for each of the Chat Servers in the Stack Exchange Network:

- [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/leave/all)
- [Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/leave/all)
- [Meta Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/chats/leave/all)

Clicking those links and then hitting the leave button will lead to you leaving all rooms without having to (re)join a chatroom first.

Comment: Cool! This answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have often noticed that I am still shown in the room after I left. And I know that it might confuse other users and somebody might be even annoyed by the fact that I am present in the room and not responding. (Maybe somebody else can confirm whether they noticed the same thing but I have sometimes seen this: I ping a user who is shown as present, and then I see their avatar disappear from the room. I suppose this happens in the cases of such "forgotten user".)

This behavior was confirmed also by other users: [Leave a chat room, but not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175168), [Persistent chat room login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181530), [Trapped – you can join a chat room, but you can never leave](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225658).

Typically, when I am leaving the room, to make sure that I did not leave my avatare behind, I do the following:

- To check whether I am still in the room, I look at some of the following: My chat profile (which shows the room I am currently in), room info of that room (which shows who is in the room), or simply the list of the chatrooms (which is where I end up after leaving the room).
- I am aware that the list of users in the room is not updated immediately - so I try to refresh a bit later. (To me it seems that checking my chat profile is a bit better - not that many users look at it, so it is less likely to be cached.)
- If I see that I am still in the room, I join *the same room* and then click leave again.

In short: To check whether I am still in some rooms, I use my chat profile. (So it's not necessary to join a room to see whether I am still present in some other room.)